# Can I directly return an object by returning constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class time
{
    public:
    time(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        hour = i, minute = j, second = k;
    }

    private:
    int hour, minute, second;
}

time return_an_object_1 (void)
{
    return time(1, 30, 59);  // Using parentheses
}

time return_an_object_2 (void)
{
    return time{1, 30, 59};  // Using curly bracket
}
```

Both can be compiled successfully, but what is the difference?

Comment: Both do the same thing, both correct.

Comment: If you use brace initialization than your last function can become `return { 1, 30, 59 };  // Using curly bracket`

Answer (score 5):

In this context, yes they are the same, but that isn't always the case. They *can* be different constructors of the same class. In the example below the class behaves differently depending on how it is constructed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class Foo {
public:
   Foo( int a, int b, int c) {
      std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
   }

   Foo( std::initializer_list<int> data) {
      std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
   }
};

int main() {
   Foo f(1, 2, 3);
   Foo o{1, 2, 3};
   return 0;
}
```